# Is there any result about the uniform convergence rate of multi-dimensional Fourier series

Tags: harmonic-analysis, fourier-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

For example in the 1-dimensional case, it is known that if f satisfies the α-Hölder condition, then
$|f(x)-(S_Nf)(x)|\le K \frac{\ln N}{N^\alpha}$
where $S_N f$ is the n-term partial sum of the Fourier series of $f$.

Is there some similar result for multi-dimensional case?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

There are a book

L. Zhizhiashvili, Trigonometric Fourier series and their conjugates, Kluwer, Dordrecht, 1996,

and a survey

Alimov, Sh.A.; Ashurov, R.R.; Pulatov, A.K. Multiple Fourier series and Fourier integrals. In:
Commutative harmonic analysis. IV: Harmonic analysis in ${\Bbb R}^n$. Encycl. Math. Sci. 42, 1-95 (Springer, 1992)

containing, in particular, conditions of the uniform convergence of multiple Fourier series similar to the classical Dini-Lipschitz condition.